# How to change meta tag in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, gulp, meta-tags

How to change meta tag in angular 2 and gulp? I try to use ng2-meta but show me errors.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>       at meta.Service.js:14

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>       at meta.module.js:8

How do i solve this peroblem ? or What method should I use?

Comment: Try to install $ npm install ng2-meta --save or npm install --save vinaygopinath/ng2-meta

Comment: I'm installed ng2-meta but don't work